# Typeahead.js Set Query From Popup Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, typeahead.js, window.opener

So currently I have a typeahead field setup up and working with a remote url. I also have a popup window which allows the user to add another element to the database. Once the new element is saved, the popup window sets the typeahead field with `window.opener.$(".typeahead").val(clientName)`. The issue is that the typeahead filed goes blank if you blur off it.

I found an issue for it here - https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/28 but I can't figure out how to incorporate it into my popup and parent window scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually used `window.opener.$('input[name=client-name]').typeahead('setQuery', clientName);` and it worked.